# Unique ways to distribute k1, k2, .. colored balls into n boxes uniquely

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Example: Uniquely distribute **2 Red Balls and 4 Blue Balls** into **3 boxes**:

```
[B][BB][RRB]
[B][BBB][RR]
[B][R][RBBB]
[B][RB][RBB]
[BB][R][RBB]
[BBB][R][RB]
```

Answer:

```
6 combinations
```

[B][B][RRBB] is not valid. Each box should be unique from other boxes.
[RRB][BB][B] is not valid. This is same as the first one.

So, how to arrive at (an algorithm is also good) unique ways to distribute N (= k1 + k2 + k3 .. km) balls into n boxes so that no two boxes has same combination.
where, ki balls are indistiguishable from each other, but distiguitable from other N-ki balls. (i = 1..m)

Went through below links with not much help:

http://scollyer-tuition.blogspot.in/2011/03/permutations-and-combinations-using.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution

[Unique ways to keep N balls into K Boxes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58753/unique-ways-to-keep-n-balls-into-k-boxes)

Comment: Something is wrong with the first row in the grey box.

Comment: Why are you citing [RB][BB][B] (which has only 5 balls) in the text as invalid and "same as the first one"  ?

Comment: right, @trueblueanil. my bad. correcting it, right away!

Comment: Is [ RBBB ] [ RB ] [ ] valid?

Comment: This is the same as the number of ways to factor $2^{k1}3^{k2}5^{k3}...$ into $n$ distinct factors.

Comment: That's true @michael. I traced came from there. But how to get to the solution?

Comment: @Henry, Actually I want a solution including blank box. But then I realized that [n boxes with blank box] =  [n-1 boxes without blank box] + [n boxes without blank box].