# between cardinality of sets their splittings and generalization

Tags: combinatorics

$V=V_{1}\sqcup V_{2}$ we will understand that V is a sum of disjont subsets $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$.If V={1} then $V_{1}=V$, $V_{2}=\emptyset$ and $V_{1}=\emptyset,V_{2}=V$ we have two possibility.If $V$={1,2}, then$V_{1}=V,V_{2}=\emptyset$ and $V_{1}$={1},$V_{2}$={2}and $V_{1}$={2},$V_{2}$={1} and $V_{1}=\emptyset$,$V_{2}=V$.We have 4 possibility.$$$$My question is if we take $V=${1,...,n} then how many possibilty occur and how it can be formulized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will have $2^n $ possibilities.

Indeed, whenever you have  $V= \{1,2,...,n \}$, you are seting $V_1$ to be a subset of $V$ , and $V_2$ to be its complement. Hence how many subsets of  $ \{1,2,...,n \}$ we have  ( including  $\phi$)? The cardinality is  $2^n$.

Comment: Thank you Nizar.Can you say any book name for this proof .If we take $V=V_{1}\sqcup...\sqcup V_{n}$  and $V_{i} \ne \emptyset$  i.e. not including $\emptyset$  then how it can be formulized ?

Comment: Sorry I dont have a specific book for the proof  I wrote. But for the problem you stated, I think you It can fomulated like  "having n  different balls, how can you distribute them  in k  boxes , so that non of the boxes is empty" right ? for this you can see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58753/unique-ways-to-keep-n-balls-into-k-boxes

Comment: Thank you very much Nizar.How we can apply this for example $V=${1,2} then $V_{1}=${1},$V_{2}=${2} and $V_{1}$={2},$V_{2}=${1} we have two possibility. $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ .

Comment: Note that  $ \dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$ is the answer for the case where all the $n$ given balls are identical.  However here in your case the numbers are not identical (what I mean is that your set is  $\{1,2 \} $  and not  $\{ 1,1\}$). Try to generalize the result to be compatible with your case. I will try also thinking for the solution. The above comment was just a hint .